# Printing largest odd number from this code

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to print the largest odd number. So far I have the code below.

```
largest = None
    for integer in range(1,11):
        integer = int(input('Enter integer #%d: ' % integer))
        if integer % 2 != 0 and (not largest or integer > largest):
            largest = integer
            if largest is None:
                print ("You didn't enter any odd numbers")
            else:
                print ("Your largest odd number was: "), max(largest)
```

I am able to enter 10 integers, but all I get is `Your largest odd number was:` instead of the largest number and that is just blank. I am trying to use the (max) to print the largest integer, but not very successfully.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and line breaks.  It is very important in python.

Comment: You shouldn't assign a new value to the loop variable `integer`. It's not illegal in Python as it is in some other languages, but it's at the very least confusing, and very rarely useful.

Comment: Anyway, part of your bug is actually related to indentation. You're doing the `if largest is None:` test inside not only the loop, but the `if integer % 2…` test. So, it will only ever print anything when you get inside that test. You want it to happen after the loop, so it has to be dedented outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
largest = None
for integer in range(1,11):
    integer = int(input('Enter integer #%d: ' % integer))
    if integer % 2 != 0 and (not largest or integer > largest):
        largest = integer
if largest is None:
    print ("You didn't enter any odd numbers")
else:
    print ("Your largest odd number was: "), largest
```

You are already assigning max value to largest, so you don't have to do max(). The function max() gives maximum of a list, `largest` is an integer not a list.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note.

1. Based on your description I've made minimum modifications to your
   code to get the desired result
2. There are a few typos in your code. eg: `range1` instead of `range`. [This was fixed in an edit by a user]
3. You are using `max` on an integer. That's not how max is supposed to be used.

check if this works

```
largest = None
for integer in range(1,11):
    integer = int(input('Enter integer #%d: ' % integer))
    if integer % 2 != 0 and (not largest or integer > largest):
        largest = integer
if largest is None:
    print ("You didn't enter any odd numbers")
else:
    print ("Your largest odd number was: "), str(largest)
```

Sharing my output

```
bash$ python test_2.py
Enter integer #1: 2
Enter integer #2: 4
Enter integer #3: 6
Enter integer #4: 8
Enter integer #5: 2
Enter integer #6: 4
Enter integer #7: 6
Enter integer #8: 8
Enter integer #9: 3
Enter integer #10: 9
Your largest odd number was:  9
```

Comment: Okay, so I put str(largest) for thelast step, but it still shows does the same thing. The code comes back with blank for an odd integer.

Comment: it's not about editing only the last step. did you try executing the entire code block in the answer? I just re-verified and it's working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `max`, you could do something like this by keeping only the odd numbers in a list.

```
odd_numbers = []
for integer in range(1, 11):
    integer = int(input('Enter integer #%d: ' % integer))
    if integer % 2 != 0:
        odd_numbers.append(integer)

if not odd_numbers:
    print("You didn't enter any odd numbers")
else:
    print("Your largest odd number was: {}".format(max(odd_numbers)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You code could be changed to:

a = range(1,11)

j = len(a) - 2

```
while j > 0:
    if a[j] % 2 == 1:
        break
    else:
        j += 1

print(a[j])
```

This would make your program iterate over your range from the largest number to the smallest. Everything else looks good. Keep going :)